# VLC: Downloads subtitles of size 0 byte

Tags: vlc

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and VLC 4.0.0.
VLC configured many times for English subs.
It searches, finds and downloads the correct subs file. 
It shows "subtitle track added" with no subs since the size of the subs file is 0 byte.

Please help.

Comment: Try the same thing with other version of VLC like 3.0.7 which is available in the Ubuntu App Store

Comment: Thank you. Will give a try. :)

Comment: So, how did it go?

Comment: Well, VLC 3.0.7 worked just the same as VLC 4.0.0. At first, it downloaded no subs at all. Then, after installing the VLC plugin (via Synaptic) downloaded & uploaded subs files of 0 size.  I can watch (with subs) only my old movies from Windows 7 & BS player times. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Is this happening with a particular video or all of them?

Comment: All of them. There is a link https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/01/download-subtitles-automatically-using-vlsub-vlc-extension/  which I tried to use but failed.